# Can I have a template for a Gitlab pipeline in my organization?

Tags: microservices, gitlab-ci

In my organization, we are in a transition phase. Big projects get split up into micro services. While this is nice to bring complexity down, the downside is that some parts which should be the same everywhere are more work.

For example, I would like every project to have some tools in the CI pipeline:

- Software Composition Analysis (SCA)
- Static Application Security Testing (SAST)
- Unit Tests

What the tools are might differ from project to project (essentially by programming language). It might also be that this changes - for example, one might want to add the type checker later. Once the type checker is there, one might enforce some of the values (while keeping others flexible, to be changed by the microservices).

Is it possible to have a shared template for a CI pipeline in GitLab? I'm not looking something people can copy-and-paste. I'm looking for a solution that allows me to adjust the CI pipeline of multiple projects at once, without causing more work for me when more microservices are added (the changes don't have to be applied instantly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

You may develop one or several templates (let's say for e.g.: a Java template (build&test), a Python one (build&test), a SonarQube (SAST), a Kubernetes (deploy), an AWS (deploy)) and then let developers/projects [include](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#includefile) the ones they need to assemble their pipeline.